# JavaFx JFoenix Tabpane not working correctly

Tags: java, javafx, windows-10, tabpanel, jfoenix

i think i found a bug in JFoenix libary and searching for a workaround.

I´m using Java 9 in a Maven Project in Eclipse (Windows 10 pro).
My JFoenix version is 9.0.8

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.jfoenix</groupId>
    <artifactId>jfoenix</artifactId>
    <version>9.0.8</version>
</dependency>
```

Problem:
When I use the Windows scaling function then my `TabPane` is not working propertly.

**With Windows scaling**

[image: TabPane with Windows scaling]

**Windows scaling**

[image: Windows scaling]

**Without Windows scaling**

[image]

**Windows scaling**

[image]

Hope its understandable.

**EDIT:**
Same problem with version 9.0.9

Comment: What are you asking about here? If you're sure about this, I'm pretty sure you can report an issue on jfoenix's webpage or repository...

Comment: I reported it https://github.com/jfoenixadmin/JFoenix/issues/1036, so maybe some know an workaround or maybe i´m doing something wrong.